# When is : equivalent to a complete vector of indices in Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

Recently I came across some Numpy exercises that I don't quite understand. The exercises use some random sample data in a 3D array:

```
import numpy as np

alpha = np.full(2000, .1)
beta = np.full(100, .1)

wordsInTopic = np.random.dirichlet(alpha, 100)

produced = np.zeros((50, 100, 2000))

for doc in range(0, 50):

    topicsInDoc = np.random.dirichlet(beta)
    wordsToTopic = np.random.multinomial(2000, topicsInDoc)

    for topic in range(0, 100):
        produced[doc, topic] = np.random.multinomial(wordsToTopic[topic], wordsInTopic[topic])
```

For example the following are equivalent, as expected:

```
print(produced[:, np.arange(0, 100, 1), :].shape)
print(produced[:, :, :].shape)
```

But the following aren't:

```
print(produced[:, np.arange(0, 100, 1), produced.sum(0).argmax(1)].shape)
print(produced[:, :, produced.sum(0).argmax(1)].shape)
```

Can someone explain what is going on here?

Comment: `:` specifies every index along an axis, that's all.

Comment: You are triggering advanced-indexing with the former. Google it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, `:` essentially says "select everything in this axis", while passing a list of indices says "select the given indices from this axis".

When you only have one list of indices, the two can be equivalent. It's easier to see with a small, 2D matrix:

```
>>> X = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(3, 3))
>>> X
array([[2, 4, 8],
       [0, 6, 9],
       [4, 2, 5]])
>>> X[:, :]
array([[2, 4, 8],
       [0, 6, 9],
       [4, 2, 5]])
>>> X[:, [0, 1, 2]]
array([[2, 4, 8],
       [0, 6, 9],
       [4, 2, 5]])
```

So that makes sense. Now, when you use two lists of indices, numpy's semantics indicate that these indices are matched pairwise (or, more generally, they are broadcast together). Consider the following:

```
>>> X[[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]
array([2, 6, 5])
```

It returns the `(0, 0)` element, the `(1, 1)` element, and the `(2, 2)` element. This kind of indexing (where you pass lists of indices) is known as *fancy indexing*, and can be incredibly powerful. You can read more on fancy indexing, and see some examples, [here](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/02.07-fancy-indexing.html) (full disclosure: this links to my own site).